# (Jetpack compose) In TextField when I try to paste text the cursor moves up or down and selects text above or below it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

```
         TextField(
                    value = text,
                    onValueChange = {
                        myViewModel.setText(it)},
                    label = null,
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(
                            "Ask me anything",
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onTertiary
                        )
                    },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 18.dp)
                        .weight(1f),
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences)
                )
```

So, for example, I put large amount of text and I want to paste something between two lines of text I long press on text field and the focus moves up and selects the text above or below

[Text copying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHvIW.gif)

Comment: Can you add the rest? The code snippet works fine. (My wild guess is that all three have the same source/onChange lamba so it jumps to the first one)

Comment: I only use one TextField. You can see the gif that I posted where the problem is

Comment: The code itself is not a reproducible example. The gif shows three TextFields in a Column.

Comment: Here, I posted again. It's only one textfield with a lot of spacing between text

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense but based on the touch events - after the popup appears you do V shape move - this is not happening because of pasting but because of touch - it does look like the intended behavior.